# Is the sequence of SQL query output is fixed or may Change?

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a `Table A`

`Table A` has 3 columns: Col1 , Col2 and Col3.
(Col1 and col2 are primary key of the `table A`)

The existing record of the table is

Query: `select * from A`

```
                   OUTPUT

  COL1              COL2        COL3
    1                 2           3 
    1                 2           5
```

if a new record is inserted values `(1,2,6)`
is it guaranteed that the new query results

```
1    2    3
1    2    5
1    2    6
```

or it possibly may result the below table as the insertion could also insertion could take place the first row:

```
1    2    6
1    2    3
1    2    5
```

and if the my select query returns output like this

```
1    2    6
1    2    3
1    2    5
```

The sql query is

```
select * from A where field1=1 and field2 = 2;
```

**Is it necessary that it will return always this sequence or this may be vary ?**

Comment: `field1 and field2 are primary key of the table A`, are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

The order of a SELECT query is not guaranteed unless you add an ORDER BY clause. If you want the order guaranteed, you can write a query like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM a
ORDER BY field3;
```

There are some ways an ORDER may be done sometimes (e.g. if a UNION is performed), but it is not guaranteed.

More information is available in [this ASKTOM post](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6257473400346237629) and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764475/oracle-sql-returns-rows-in-arbitrary-fashion-when-no-order-by-clause-is-used).

Comment: can you suggest some way in which I can verify ?

Comment: What do you mean, verify?

Comment: I've added some references to my answer.